# do database JOINs make many copies of data in left and right sides of join?

Tags: sql, join

I'm curious: do databases return `JOIN`s as the results of two (or more) `SELECT` statements with pointers from (segments of) rows in the left side to (segments of) rows in the right, or do they return result sets which may contain many copies of entries from the left and right sides?

You can imagine this being particularly inefficient for dense N:N relations, where N copies of a row on the left might be made to pair up with N matches on the right, and vice versa.

You could hide this optimization in client drivers and make it totally transparent to the database user.

**EDIT** To clarify, by "dense N:N relations," I mean something like (for a "Facebook clone") you have a "users" table and a "friends" table, and each user is friends with every other user. You would need two `JOIN`s to pull all the pairs of friends out, but could pass the same information to the client as the result of three `SELECT` statements and let the client match up rows using pointers instead of actually duplicating each user 2(N-1) times (N-1 times on the left, N-1 times on the right).

Comment: What DB platform are you asking about?

Comment: @JohnFx I'm most curious about commonly-used production databases (Oracle/PostgreSQL/MySQL/SQLServer/DB2/etc) but any/all information would be interesting to me.

Comment: If you want data to artificially do this: "where N copies of a row on the left might be made to pair up with N matches on the right," then you need to create a row-number. What fool thought up a design intended to abuse the RDBMS in such a fashion?

Comment: In whatever platform you can usually get a query plan that pretty much shows you exactly how the RDBMS executes the query. This book is also a really good resource: http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/inside-sql-server-query-optimizer

Comment: A DBMS will generally avoid doing as much work as possible, for as long as possible, and will try to avoid making copies of data in the database.  Some databases are more skilled at avoiding work than others, and the query may force its hand, but the work done is likely to be close to the minimum that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you did request from a database a result set based on an n:n relationship then it would presumably be because this represents a real situation -- that many people buy products from many shops, for example. It's not inefficient to represent this real situation in such a way, because the result set is simply a representation of the truth.

In general an n:n relationship would need three relations to be joined -- database normalisation effectively forbids n:n relationships between two tables, for equijoins at any rate.